# Why doesn't this P/Invoke signature work?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, pinvoke

I trying to marshaling C# code from WinApi functions..
But i understand.. WHYYY WHYY she dont work! Filepath - is correct, handle is taken.
Can anyone help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ChangeFileTime
{

    class Program
    {

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetFileTime(IntPtr hFile, ref long lpCreationTime,
                                                            ref long lpLastAccessTime, 
                                                            ref long lpLastWriteTime);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFilename,
                                              uint dwDesiredAccess,
                                              uint dwShareMode,
                                              IntPtr SecurityAttributes,
                                              uint dwCreationDisposition,
                                              uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
                                              IntPtr hTemplateFile);


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
            const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
            const uint FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x00000002;
            const uint FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 128;

            IntPtr ptr = CreateFile("C:\\file.txt", GENERIC_READ,
                                                    FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                                    IntPtr.Zero,
                                                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                                                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                                    IntPtr.Zero);

            DateTime creation_time = new DateTime(1990, 12, 14);

            long file_time = creation_time.ToFileTime();
            DateTime time = DateTime.FromFileTime(file_time);

            SetFileTime(ptr, ref file_time, ref file_time, ref file_time);
            int a = 20;
        }
    }
}
```

I think i got mistake.. i try to write C++ code, and she work fine.. but why in C# dont work?

Comment: What's the part that don't work. CreateFile or SetFileTime?

Comment: Sorry. SetFileTime doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you use the provided .NET API instead of trying to write C++?

Comment: And what error do you get? (don't forget to specify SetLastError=true: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetFileTime.html)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: this is education exemple.. i know about File.SetLastWriteTime("C:\\file.txt", new DateTime(2000, 12, 15));

Comment: @HenkHolterman I mean, access time dont change at file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The handle must have been created using the CreateFile function with
>   the FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES

This should work:

```
const uint FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0100;
IntPtr ptr = CreateFile("C:\\file.txt", FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, //...
```